# How to return json result from function?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to return a Json request, but it is always null. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong...

```
  /* GetTasksByDateRange */
this.fnGetTasksByDateRange = function (dateFilter)
{
    /* Get tasks by date range */
    var oData = {};

    var jsonTaskData = $.getJSON('/Planner/Planner/GetTasksByDateRange', { 'dateFilter': dateFilter }, function (jsonTaskData)
    {
        oData = jsonTaskData;
    });

    return oData;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`oData` hasn't been set at that point. You will need to have the *asynchronous* function call another, passing it the data.

Comment: Could you give an example of this?

Comment: `function (jsonTaskData) { someOtherFunction(jsonTaskData) }`

Comment: So there's no way to set it to a variable so I can return it from the function it is in?

Comment: You don't **have** a value yet. AJAX is **asynchronous**.